# Should I use a 'default' key in an object

Tags: javascript, object, default, config

I'm writing a JS app and I'd like to set up a config object.
I have the following part:

```
var config = {
    localization: {
        locales: ['en', ..., 'de'],
        defaultLocale: 'en'
    }
}
```

I'd like use `'default': 'en'` instead of `defaultLocale: 'en'`, but would that be OK? Both would be valid I think.

Note: I don't want to use the first element of the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`default` is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) word in `switch` statement. You can use it like this:

```
localization : {
    "locales": ['en', ..., 'de'],
    "default": 'en'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Even though 'default' is a keyword in javascript, "default" as a string isn't.

```
default : 'en'  // bad

"default" : 'en' // good
```

Just remember that you'll likely have to reference it as localization["default"] to avoid syntax errors.  (localization.default might be possible, but I haven't tested it.)

It's probably not a best practice, but you can do it if you're careful.